# How to convert Hexadecimal to Decimal in bash/scripting by only using functions

Tags: arrays, bash, function, scripting, hex

hello there I am very new to bash programming and for an assignment, they have tasked me with converting from all base types to all other bases (one conversion at a time) example: decimal to binary, binary to decimal, hexadecimal to binary and back etc.. the catch is we are not allowed to use any type of tricks or shortcuts such as using bc, poisix or any kind of oneliner solutions.. even printf is off limits. we need to use our own functions like here is one I did for binary to decimal

```
for (( x=0; num>0; x++ )); do
  em=$(echo $(( $num % 2 )))#divides num in 2 remainder gets stored in rem, num #keeps the same value
  num=$(( $num/2))#num gets divided by two and stores its new value
  array[x]=$rem
done

#printing part
if [ $x=0 ]; then #dont know why it doesnt work if i take this "if" out.
  for (( x=${#array[@]}-1; x>=0; x-- )); do #prints all remainders backwards
    echo "${array[x]"
  done
fi
```

so hopefully you now know what I mean by "no shortcuts or tricks"..
so here is the actual problem I'm facing now..
you see in this conversion the value of num was introduced by a user via:
 `read num`
but now I need to convert a hexadecimal to decimal value.. I'm not sure if to use an array or what else I could do to evaluate the characters inside a variable that contains both numbers and letters and at the same time evaluate or compare them.. I was thinking of trying:
if [ ${array[x]} -eq "A" ]; then
array[x]=10
but okay...
how do I take apart a value introduced like this: 6C3 and store each character separately inside an array while maintaining its value and be able to compare it/ do operations..
any help is appreciated thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm *really* curious to know what they're trying to teach you with this assignment...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : This looks like an exercise to really "put hair on your chest" ;-) Or possibly, the O.P. works in an industry where detailed knowledge of base conversions is a key skill? Good luck to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was always told you convert a number from one base to another by converting single digit from the back in that number and then multiply that number by the base and position it is in.

First I wrote a function to convert a single digit from hex to dec. Then I convert the number from the most significant digit (from the one to the left) to dec, then multiply by 16, then add the next digit, then mutliply by 16 and so on.

```
hextodec1() {
        case "$1" in
        [0-9]) echo "$1"; ;;
        a|A) echo 10; ;;
        b|B) echo 11; ;;
        c|C) echo 12; ;;
        d|D) echo 13; ;;
        e|E) echo 14; ;;
        f|F) echo 15; ;;
        esac
}

out=0
for ((i = ${#num} - 1; i >= 0; --i)); do
        ((out = out * 16 + $(hextodec1 ${num:$i:1}) ))
done
echo $out
```

You can extract a substring of string by using `${variable_name:$start_position:$length}`.
But really the simplest way is to do this:

```
echo $((0x$num))
```

You algorithm needs some fixing because bash understands decimal numbers by default, or hexadecimal numbers if pretended with `0x`. So you loop `for (( x=0; num>0; x++ )); do` will not work for `num=6C3` cause num is a string, and bash can't compare number `x` to string `6C3`. You can do `for ((x=0;(0x$num)>0;++x)); do` but then you might better just `echo $((0x$num))`, cause the first time you will `num=$(( (0x$num) % 2 ))` it will be converted to decimal and the next time bash enters the loop condition the variable will be in decimal not hex.